# How to Embed Web Server in OSGi Framework?

Tags: webserver, osgi, bundle, httpserver

I'd like to know how do I run a HTTP server into an OSGi platform. I am currently using Equinox and found some official info about embedding Jetty bundle, but links to dependencies seem broken and overall it isn't well documented. (http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_equinox.php)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at Apache Felix Http service http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html Since these are well designed OSGi bundles, they run also in Equinox.

I am using their whiteboard model, with this bundle you just register a Servlet with a service property. If you want to check this all out, suggest you download bndtools and create a runtime with webconsole and DS. This is ALL you have to write for a Hello World servlet:

```
package com.example;

@Component(alias="/hello", provide=Servlet.class)
public MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp) {
     rsp.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
     rsp.getOutputStream().write("Hello World".getBytes("UTF-8"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also Pax-Web, which gives you a ton of features.
Take a look at http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web.
It suports std. Http- service, whiteboard exrender for Servlets, filters, jsps.
And also war (either std or with osgi manifest).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.0.3.RELEASE/docs/virgo-programmer-guide/html/ch02s02.html): it's based on equinox and integrates tomcat.

As for Jetty server, it is for sure embeddable into OSGi: the [Apache CXF project uses jetty](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jetty-configuration.html) to serve SOAP requests and CXF runs in OSGi without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to have corresponding bundles installed to your embedded OSGI framework. There   is a code sample: https://bitbucket.org/vbashur/diff/ Take a look on **osgimain** and **osgiservice** projects